# What does $(\mathbb C\backslash\{0\})\times\mathbb R$ mean?

Tags: notation, complex-numbers

What does $$(\mathbb C\backslash\{0\})\times\mathbb R$$ mean, and how does it look like?

Thanks.

Comment: It's the cartesian product of a set C without an element called "o" by a set called R. If you meant the complex and the real fields resp. then....well, then it is the same as explained above.

Comment: And in the latter case it would "look" like a full 3D space with a single line missing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The notation $(\mathbb C\backslash\{0\})\times\mathbb R$ refers to the set of points of the form $(a + bi,c)$ where $i^2 = -1$; $a,b$ and $c$ are real numbers; and at least one of $a$ and $b$ is non-zero.