# What is $\mathbb{C} \backslash \{0\}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, complex-numbers, notation

At first I thought is it just $\mathbb{C}$ without the point $(0,0) = 0+i0$ i.e. a punctured disk, puctured at the origin

But after reading [What does $(\mathbb C\backslash\{0\})\times\mathbb R$ mean?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/692581/what-does-mathbb-c-backslash-0-times-mathbb-r-mean) I am not so confident that I am correct. Because in that answer someone remarked $\{0\}$ as being a "symbol"...

Can someone please explain the meaning of this notation, and also $\mathbb{R}^2\backslash \{0\}$

Comment: It is indeed the punctured complex plane, missing only the origin. So is $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$. This is entirely consistent with the material to which you linked.

Comment: Technically $\Bbb R^2$ doesn't have an element specifically written as $0$, so I would say that $\Bbb R^2\setminus \{0\}=\Bbb R^2$.  It does however have a zero element which is written as $(0,0)$.  If by $0$ they are being lazy and using the symbol $0$ to refer to the zero element $(0,0)$, then yes it is the punctured plane.  I would not have written it that way however, instead writing it as $\Bbb R^2\setminus \{(0,0)\}$.  Note the difference between this and $(\Bbb R\setminus \{0\})^2$ which not only is missing the origin, but is missing the axes as well.

Comment: @JMoravitz That kind of set-based interpretation isn't useful for any kind of problem. Surely you should take $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{0\}$ to mean the plane with the zero vector removed. The notation isn't unambiguous, but to even consider it as meaning removing the literal number $0$ from $\mathbb{R}^2$ is just kind of silly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$ is exactly the punctured disk you mentioned.

In your question, they cartesian-multiplied it with $\mathbb R$ producing "the set of points of the form $(a + bi,c)$ where $i^2 = -1$; $a,b$ and $c$ are real numbers; and at least one of $a$ and $b$ is non-zero."

---

$\mathbb R^2\setminus\{0\}$ is also what you would expect, i.e. $(a,b)$ where at least one of $a$ and $b$ is non-zero.

Answer (score 1):

what is the reason for your doubt? $\mathbb{C}\backslash \{0\}$ is, in fact just the punctured disc.

And, actually, $0+i0=0$.